# How to test if an EventSubscriber exists in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Before deleting an EventSubscriber with SourceIdentifier "abc", I want to test if it exists and only then delete it.  Otherwise there is no need to.

But every time I access it to test if it exists with:

```
Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "abc"
```

Powershell responds with an error:

```
get-eventsubscriber : Event subscription with source identifier 'abc' does not exist.        
At line:1 char:8
+ $chk = get-eventsubscriber -SourceIdentifier "abc"
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-EventSubscriber], Argu
           mentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : INVALID_SOURCE_IDENTIFIER,Microsoft.PowerShell.C
           ommands.GetEventSubscriberCommand
```

stating that it does not exist.  Is there a way to avoid the error messages and instead set a variable to null or false that can be tested to see if it does not exist?

Something like:

```
$eventSubscriberExists = Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "abc"    
if ($eventSubscriberExists) {
    Unregeister-Event -SourceIdentifier "abc"
}
```

In other words instead of sending error messages to the console, set a variable to true or false.

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: Thank you.  Exactly what was needed.

Comment: Furthermore, if you need the actual error for diagnostic purposes, use `-ErrorVariable` (passing the name of a variable, without `$`).